# Quiero guardar datos en un vector de tipo char, pero no me deja guardarlo en sus posiciones. Como podria hacer?

Tags: array, c

```
Quiero guardar datos en un vector de tipo char, pero no me deja guardarlo en sus posiciones. 
Como podria hacer ?


char *E[3];

for(i=0;i<2;i++){
printf("INDRUCUCE VALOR PARA ARRAY CHAR \n");
scanf("%s",E[i]);}

E[1]="SI FUNCIONA";
```

/*si asigno esto si imprime bien pero quiero guardar y despues imprimir */

```
printf("EL ARRAY 2 ES (%s)\n",E[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tiene muchos errores tu código, una cadena de caracteres en C en un ARRAY de caracteres, con cada letra en una posicion y terminando en '\0' como último elemento. Te paso un ejemplo de como declaro una cadena ( un char[] ), escaneo letra por letra e imprimo la cadena completa o alguna letra que quiera:

```
int main (){
    
  char E[3]; // ARRAY de caracteres (o cadena)
  int i; // hay que declarar i antes de usar el for
  
  for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++){ 
    printf ("INDRUCUCE VALOR PARA ARRAY CHAR \n");
    scanf ("%s", &E[i]); // leyendo caracter por caracter
  }

  printf ("El el array de chars es: %s\n", E); // imprimo la cadena 
  printf ("La ultima posicion es: %s", &E[2]); // imprimo el ultimo caracter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que una cadena de caracteres es un arreglo de caracteres (`char[]`) o si lo prefieres un puntero a caracteres contiguos en memoria (`char*`).

En el primer caso, un arreglo es una variable. A toda variable le corresponde un espacio en la memoria.

Por lo tanto, puedes ejecutar el siguiente código:

```
char buffer[20];
scanf("%s", buffer);
```

---

En el segundo caso (`char*`), no puedes simplemente hacerlo así:

```
char *cadena;
scanf("%s", cadena);
```

Porque un puntero es una variable que solo guarda una dirección de memoria.

Necesitas que el puntero apunte a una región de memoria válida. Bien podría apuntar a un arreglo (en el stack), a un literal o a una parte del heap.

```
// Memoria en el stack
char buffer[20];

char *cadena = buffer;
scanf("%s", cadena);
...

// Reservas memoria del heap
cadena = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
scanf("%s", cadena);
...
// Cuando no la usas más debes liberarla
free(cadena);
```

---

Ahora podrás entender el problema más fácilmente.

`char *E[3]` es un arreglo de 3 punteros y lo explicado en la sección anterior también aplica aquí.

Los 3 punteros están sin inicializar. Por lo tanto apuntan a direcciones indeterminadas.

Así que nuevamente, necesitas un lugar donde guardar las cadenas.

Puedes hacerlo así:

```
// No es necesario que sean todas del mismo tamaño
char cadena1[20];
char cadena2[20];
char cadena3[20];

// Al declarar el arreglo lo puedes inicializar así
char *E[3] = { cadena1, cadena2, cadena3 };

for(i=0;i<2;i++){
    printf("INDRUCUCE VALOR PARA ARREGLO CHAR \n");
    scanf("%s",E[i]);
}
```